# UINavBarController connecting the same UIViewController to multiple navigation controllers

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a storyboarded app with a chain of tableviews followed by a detail view. Kind of the classic iPhone app. There are 4 tabs and each one leads to a navigation controller.

[image: Storyboard]

The issue is I really want to avoid unnecessary glue code since the app is basically finished. If it was possible to connect the Search and Favorites (bottom two off the tab bar) controller as 'Root View Controllers' to the same UIViewController I would be done. However, this won't work since a view controller can only be the root view controller to one tab. So as you can see I've instituted two dummy UIViewControllers that forward you to the UIViewController in the middle. Now, unfortunately, I have to write code to make that central view controller a fake root view controller to disable the appearance of the back button, and prevent popping to the blank root when you double-tap the tab bar.

Has anyone got a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a flaw in Storyboards. One workaround would be to use simple view controllers for each navigation controller's `rootViewController`. Put a `UIContainerView` in each that points to the UIViewController you want to share.

Comment: Interesting solution. I ended up segueing from essentially empty root view controllers, but this would work as well.